# Symfony2: how to configure path for saving file

Tags: symfony

how can I setup a file path in a class for saving a file?
I already tried a relative path but this change if I call the class from a controller or from a command container...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller class:

```
...
$path = $this->get("kernel")->getRootDir();
...
```

`$path` variable will be path to `app` directory of Symfony project.

```
...
$path = $this->get("kernel")->getRootDir() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ".." . PATH_SEPARATOR;
```

`$path` variable will be path do root directory of project.

From command class:

```
...
$path = $this->getContainer()->get("kernel")->getRootDir();
...
```